# Survival analysis with a probability lower than 1 at the start

Tags: r, probability, survival-analysis

I'm trying to create a graph that shows the probability of a song reaching the top 10 of the Billboard Hot 100 over time (weeks in chart). When a song enters the chart, the probability should be something like 0.15, which would decline every week that comes next. Hence the chart should be a declining curve starting at 0.15, with x (weeks in chart) and y (probability of reaching the top 10).

1) Can I use a Kaplan-Meier curve to do this?

2) How can I create a Kaplan-Meier curve in R (survival package) that does not start at a probability of 1?

Comment: I am unsure what you want to achieve? Do you want to have a curve for individual songs? Kaplan-Meier curves are for survival data for binary time-to-event data (so the curve goes down the moment 1 of the people in the population gets the outcome), not for modelling probabilities for one individual (whether a person or song)

Comment: I want to show the probability curve for any song to reach the top 10 (so one curve for the entire dataset of 6000 songs). The event (binary) is reaching the top 10 and the curve should indeed go down when a song has reached the top 10 (or leaves the chart entirely). So:

Week 0: probability of a song to reach the top 10 at some point in the future.

Week 1: probability of a song that has not yet reached the top 10 in week 1, to reach it at some point in the future.

Week 2: etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question. I think maybe stats.stackexchange.com will have more to say about it.

I don't think this is analogous to survival and therefore I think Kaplan-Meier or any other survival estimators won't do what you are looking for.

This is a time-to-event problem of a kind; a web search for that term might turn up some resources. But it's not a survival or reliability problem because the event in question doesn't eventually happen to all subjects (as death or mechanical failure does). In fact the event in question is pretty rare.

My advice is just bite the bullet and compute the probabilities yourself, by counting songs which reach the top 10. The basic statement you mentioned is just computing p[k] = m[k]/n[k] where for convenience I've defined m[k] = (number of songs which stayed on chart at least k weeks and eventually reached top 10) and n[k] = (number of songs which stayed on chart at least k weeks). I think p[k] is not necessarily monotonic in k -- I wouldn't be surprised if there is a bump in there. Something to look for, anyway.

Songs which fall off the chart and go back onto it kind of mess up the picture a little. My advice is to treat them as if they were on the chart the whole time. But you might very well have a different idea about how to handle them.

I can see an interesting variation. How about p[j, k] = (proportion of songs which eventually reach top 10 after at least k weeks on chart and current chart position is j) ? or how about the same, but for the initial position is j? No doubt there are others.

Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 2):

Kinda...sorta...not really.

First, you probably don't want a typical Kaplan-Meier curve, which plots the survival function.  You want the complement, or the cumulative incidence. (`1 - S(x)`).  This will start the plot at a probability of 0, indicating that the no songs are in the top ten at the very moment they are released (kinda, sorta)

For songs that are released and are in the top then their first week, you would need to mark the follow up time as 0, with the top ten flag as 1.  In this manner, although the step function technically starts at zero, it will have an immediate step up to the proportion of songs that premier in the top ten their first week.

For example:

```
library(survival)

df <-
  data.frame(song = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
             # number of weeks followed before reaching top ten
             # (or truncation)
             weeks_followed = c(0, 3, 4, 13, 1),
             topten = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

fit <- survfit(Surv(weeks_followed, topten) ~ 1,
               data = df)

plot(fit,
     conf.int = FALSE,
     # 1 - survival 
     fun = function(x) 1 - x,
     xlim = c(0, 13),
     ylim = c(0, 1))
```

Which yields the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this comes close to what I'm trying to achieve. Any ideas on how to show that the chance of a song to reach the top 10 is actually declining per week in the chart (downward curve)?

Comment: For that, I think you'd probably be better off showing either a line chart or bar chart with number of weeks since release on the x-axis, and the proportion of songs that reached the top then on that week on the y-axis. On the cumulative incidence plot, you can make the same observation by noting that the slope of the "tangent line" (if you were to plot a continuous curve through the step function) is approaching zero as time goes by.